# PHP 7 install on Ubuntu 14.04 now fails due to libssl dependency that can't be resolved?

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, php-7

I am using shippable to build my project and part of it requires PHP.

The build script is this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties language-pack-en-base
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-bcmath
```

Today the build failed while installing PHP with the following error:

```
apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-bcmath

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.0 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.0-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.0-cgi but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: php7.0-common but it is not going to be installed
 php7.0-bcmath : Depends: php7.0-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So i started up a local docker container to see if something wierd was happening at shippable - with the following command:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

And ran the 5 build lines listed above, and i get the same error. The next thing i did was install `aptitude` to see if i could get a better error, and ran this `aptitude install -y php7.0 php7.0-bcmath` - this was the aptitude output:

```
aptitude install -y php7.0 php7.0-bcmath
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2{a} apache2-bin{a} apache2-data{a} libapache2-mod-php7.0{ab} 
  libapr1{a} libaprutil1{a} libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3{a} libaprutil1-ldap{a} 
  libedit2{a} php-common{a} php7.0 php7.0-bcmath php7.0-cli{ab} 
  php7.0-common{ab} php7.0-json{a} php7.0-opcache{a} php7.0-readline{a} 
  psmisc{a} ssl-cert{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 4950 kB of archives. After unpacking 20.2 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-cli : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) which is a virtual package.
 php7.0-common : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) which is a virtual package.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libapache2-mod-php7.0 [Not Installed]              
2)     php7.0 [Not Installed]                             
3)     php7.0-bcmath [Not Installed]                      
4)     php7.0-cli [Not Installed]                         
5)     php7.0-common [Not Installed]                      
6)     php7.0-json [Not Installed]                        
7)     php7.0-opcache [Not Installed]                     
8)     php7.0-readline [Not Installed]                    



The following NEW packages will be installed:
  psmisc{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.2 kB of archives. After unpacking 229 kB will be used.
Get: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main psmisc amd64 22.20-1ubuntu2 [53.2 kB]
Fetched 53.2 kB in 0s (911 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package psmisc.
(Reading database ... 14894 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../psmisc_22.20-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking psmisc (22.20-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up psmisc (22.20-1ubuntu2) ...
```

I have a couple of questions:

**1) How do i fix this? I have done some looking but can't work out how to update libssl**

**2) Why has this happened all of a sudden, this was never a problem for PHP7.0 before?**

Some additional info:

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
built on: Mon Jan 30 20:38:38 UTC 2017
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"

uname -a
Linux b5cbe94d7da8 4.9.13-moby #1 SMP Sat Mar 25 02:48:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is it the same problem with this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/462094/unable-to-install-libssl1-0-0i386-due-to-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I think this is offtopic here on StackOverflow.  This belongs on Ask Ubuntu or something.

Comment: @TahaPaksu as an Ubuntu administrator I can say "No, but it's a similar issue and it's with the repository being specified by the programmers/users, NOT the scripts being used to build things, and ultimately is not able to be resolved by the end-user or people creating packages."  It needs resolved by the people running that repository/PPA

Comment: The ppa in question has an [issue tracker](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues) and there's already an [issue](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/639) for this particular problem. And it has been already solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PPA maintainer has 'fixed' this, [according to a GitHub issue](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/639).

To answer your questions:

> 1) How do i fix this? I have done some looking but can't work out how to update libssl

The PPA has been already fixed, but next time, please, fill an issue at appropriate place - e.g. the [issue tracker](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues).

> 2) Why has this happened all of a sudden, this was never a problem for PHP7.0 before?

The packages in [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) build-depends on [ppa:ondrej/apache2](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2) that has been recently updated to OpenSSL 1.1.0 libraries, and those were picked up by latest build of PHP.  The [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) had to be updated with OpenSSL 1.1.0 libraries as well as a consequence of this move.

A bug or two occasionally happens, and it is fixed as soon as the bug is filled at appropriate place.

It is perfectly safe to mix more versions of OpenSSL even in the same binary becase OpenSSL uses proper [SONAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname)s and all the symbols in the shared library are [versioned](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning).